# Transform result of `st_bbox()` to other CRS

Tags: r, transform, geospatial, r-sf

Is there a simple way to transform the bounding of a simple feature (`sf` object) to another CRS?

The result of the function `st_bbox()` is of class `bbox`. It is not possible to use `st_transform()` to transform it to another CRS.

I am using a calculated bounding box based `EPSG: 28992`:

```
sf::st_bbox(xmin = 187470, xmax =194587, 
            ymin = 409753, ymax = 412715,  
            crs = st_crs(28992))
```

Now I want to transform this box to `EPSG:4326`

Comment: Note that a rectangle in one coordinate system might not be a rectangle in another. If you really want to project the full shape of the box rather than just the four corners, then you need to create a rectangular polygon with more vertices along the sides, and project *that*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a `st_as_sfc` method for `bbox` objects, so we can transform a `bbox` like this:

```
library(sf)

bb = sf::st_bbox(c(xmin = 187470, xmax =194587, 
                   ymin = 409753, ymax = 412715),  
                 crs = st_crs(28992))

bb_ll = st_bbox(
  st_transform(
    st_as_sfc(bb), 
    4326
  )
)

# or pipey
library(magrittr)

bb_ll = bb %>%
  st_as_sfc() %>%
  st_transform(crs = 4326) %>%
  st_bbox()

bb_ll

    xmin      ymin      xmax      ymax 
5.856639 51.675176  5.959866 51.702257
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to make an intermediate `sfc_MULTIPOINT`, transform it to 4326, then extract the bounding box from that object:

```
pts <- st_multipoint(rbind(c(187470, 409753), c(194587, 412715))) %>% st_sfc(crs = st_crs(28992))
pts <- pts %>% st_transform(crs = 4326)

st_bbox(pts)

     xmin      ymin      xmax      ymax 
 5.856639 51.675634  5.959866 51.701799
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @spacedman, a rectangle in one coordinate system might not be a rectangle in another. Some coordinate systems are much more curved than others!

To more safely transform a bounding box, you could add vertices using st_make_grid(n = whatever).

```
# pipey code to show the steps clearly
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
bb_better_reproj = bb_orig %>% 
                      st_make_grid(n=10) %>%  #this also makes it into a polygon
                      st_transform(crs = 4326) %>% 
                      st_bbox()
```

This isn't 100% safe, but better than just transforming the rectangular polygon (which only transforms the corner vertices, nothing in between). Too many grid vertices is really slow. I find ~10-20 work well in most cases.

An example (using different Coordinate Reference Systems (CRS) than the OP to illustrate):

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

bb_orig = st_bbox(c(xmin = 40, xmax =-40, 
                    ymin = 45, ymax = 55), 
                    crs = st_crs(4326)) #lag/long

new_crs = 3995 # arctic polar stereographic

bb_simple_reproj = bb_orig %>% 
                   st_as_sfc() %>% 
                   st_transform(crs=new_crs) %>% 
                   st_bbox

bb_better_reproj = bb_orig %>% 
                   st_make_grid(n=10) %>%  
                   st_transform(crs = new_crs) %>% 
                   st_bbox()

# 100 random points inside the original bounding box (grey)
  sample_from_bb_orig = st_sample(st_as_sfc(bb_orig), 1000) %>%
  st_transform(new_crs)

  plot(st_geometry(sample_from_bb_orig), col="grey")

# if the bbox was only transformed as simple rectangle we would get (red):
  # red points indicate those missed by the simple bbox reprojection -- note that many are missed!
  plot(st_geometry(st_as_sfc(bb_simple_reproj)), border="red", add=TRUE)
  plot(st_difference(sample_from_bb_orig, st_as_sfc(bb_simple_reproj)) , col="red", add=TRUE)

# using 'better' repojection, with more vertices added (blue)
  # blue points indicate those missed by the simple bbox reprojection
  plot(st_geometry(st_as_sfc(bb_better_reproj)), border="blue", add=TRUE)
  plot(st_difference(sample_from_bb_orig, st_as_sfc(bb_better_reproj)) , col="blue", pch="x", add=TRUE)
```