# Subsetting ncdf file using stars package in R

Tags: r, netcdf, r-stars

I am trying to subset a climatic variable from Copernicus.

```
devtools::install_github("r-spatial/stars")
library(stars)

library(ncdf4)
library(RNetCDF)

pp <- read_ncdf("~/climate_data/pp_ens_mean_0.1deg_reg_v25.0e.nc", proxy = TRUE)

> print(pp)
netcdf source stars proxy object from:
[1] "[...]/pp_ens_mean_0.1deg_reg_v25.0e.nc"

Available nc variables:
pp

dimension(s):
          from    to         offset  delta  refsys point values x/y
longitude    1   705       -25.0001    0.1  WGS 84    NA   NULL [x]
latitude     1   465        24.9999    0.1  WGS 84    NA   NULL [y]
time         1 26298 1950-01-01 UTC 1 days POSIXct    NA   NULL
```

This is what I get as a proxy.

I would like to subset between 10°E and 25°E in longitude, and 55°N and 70°N in latitude.
I tried this but it is not working and I do not really figure out why.

```
pp <- read_ncdf(pp, 
                var = pp, 
                ncsub = cbind(start = c(10, 55, 1), 
                               count = c(25, 70, 26298)))
```

Any ideas? Many thanks for the precious help.

Comment: No error thrown, just didn't do the hoped for result subset?

Comment: Yes you are right, sorry for missing it: Large netcdf source found, returning proxy object.
Warning message:
In read_ncdf(pp, var = pp, ncsub = cbind(start = c(10, 55, 1), count = c(25,  :
  ncsub ignored when .x is class nc_proxy

Comment: As it might help 'unmuddy' the calls, perhaps start again in a new session with just `stars`, not `ncdf4` and `RNetCDF`. And we will agree to read [stars vignettes 2 being proxy](https://r-spatial.github.io/stars/articles/), after coffee?

Comment: Perhaps `bb = st_bbox(c(xmin=10.00, ymin=55.00, xmax=25.00, ymax=70.00))` for bounding box then `pp_sub = pp[bb]`? Pots of coffee.

Comment: many thanks for your help (sorry I do not get the coffee part but I am not mother tongue in english). I have managed another approach, but I will test yours, using tidync::hyper_filter() : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72928365/how-to-match-converted-time-with-metadata-in-netcdf-file. If you want to post your last answer I can accept it as a valid answer ;)

Comment: As you have the data, please test. It may, even with bbox, still be 'too big' to be in memory ( I read you have a lot, my RAM 8G), but `stars` seems designed for these problems.

Comment: > pp_sub = pp[bb]
Error in st_crop.stars_proxy(x, i, ..., collect = FALSE) : 
  for cropping, the CRS of both objects has to be identical / This is the error message that I am getting, I am trying to solve it

Comment: Change the [CRS of bbox to your pp CRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55050684/transform-result-of-st-bbox-to-other-crs)

Comment: I think that it is working! > print(pp_sub)
netcdf source stars proxy object from:
[1] "[...]/pp_ens_mean_0.1deg_reg_v25.0e.nc"

Available nc variables:
pp

dimension(s):
          from    to         offset  delta  refsys point values x/y
longitude  351   501       -25.0001    0.1  WGS 84    NA   NULL [x]
latitude   301   451        24.9999    0.1  WGS 84    NA   NULL [y]
time         1 26298 1950-01-01 UTC 1 days POSIXct    NA   NULL

Comment: Now, write up your work flow as an answer and accept it. Glad progress is being made. Certainly subsequent problems can crop up and become new questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer thanks to @Chris:

```
devtools::install_github("r-spatial/stars")
library(stars)

library(ncdf4)
library(RNetCDF)

pp <- read_ncdf("C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/~/climate_data/pp_ens_mean_0.1deg_reg_v25.0e.nc", proxy = TRUE)

print(pp)

bb = st_bbox(c(xmin=10.00, ymin=55.00, 
               xmax=25.00, ymax=70.00),
               crs = st_crs(4326))

pp_sub = pp[bb]

> print(pp_sub)
netcdf source stars proxy object from:
[1] "[...]/pp_ens_mean_0.1deg_reg_v25.0e.nc"

Available nc variables:
pp

dimension(s):
          from    to         offset  delta  refsys point values x/y
longitude  351   501       -25.0001    0.1  WGS 84    NA   NULL [x]
latitude   301   451        24.9999    0.1  WGS 84    NA   NULL [y]
time         1 26298 1950-01-01 UTC 1 days POSIXct    NA   NULL
```

Comment: Forgot to ask, but did you get `values`?